# Tracing .Net Framework event back to application

Tags: .net, antivirus, solidworks

First off I have no experience in this, I am just trying to substantiate some claims being made.

we are using WebRoot Endpoint Protection on our workstations and server. We also use SolidWorks to directly access models from the server. The problem is the open and saves times are ridiculously slow. I wrote a little listener macro for SolidWorks that records the save time per KB which is showing upwards of 3 Sec/KB! SolidWorks seems to top out at using 3% to 5% of our 1GBS connections. Any other program, AutoCAD, Excel, and out FEA software have no problem accessing files on the server.

I think the problem is that WebRoot is not compatible with SolidWorks (it's not on the list of SolidWorks approved AV). WebRoot is calming to have added exceptions to SolidWorks files but we have seen no improvement. From what I understand is that WebRoot monitors the .NET Framework activity which SolidWorks uses heavily to access model files so it does not have to directly open them. It is my suspicion that WebRoot is slowing down or altogether blocking the .NET Framework activity from SolidWorks. This would also help explain all the file reference loss issues we have that I have never seen in the absence of WebRoot.

My question is that is it even possible for WebRoot to trace where the .NET Framework activity is coming from? And if it is would that affect performance? If they just downright let any and all .NET Framework activity affect any kind of SolidWorks file would it not be a major hole in security and would just render WebRoot useless.

Again I am no expert in this so all I'm looking for is just a general answer from someone other than WebRoot on whether or not this is possible.

Comment: can you check the logs from [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) in both cases w/ and w/o WebRoot working? There should be a clear indication that this is happening.

Comment: So I ran Process Monitor while just opening and saving a SolidWorks file. Like I said most of this is over my head so I'm not sure what I am looking at. I will have to have IT disable WebRoot but what should I be looking for in differences in the logs?

Comment: hard to tell what specific things too look for. I would start with File summary and check the times that are spent on those files and go from there.